# Проблема с панелью в css

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы панель была изначально выдвинута, и только после нажатия закрывалась, и её опять можно было бы выдвинуть?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53w2j80e)

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.nav {
  width: 500px;
  min-width: 500px;
  /* фиксируем и выставляем высоту панели на максимум */
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  /* сдвигаем (прячем) панель относительно правого края страницы */
  right: -500px;
  /* внутренние отступы */
  padding: 15px 20px;
  /* плавный переход смещения панели */
  -webkit-transition: right 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: right 0.3s;
  transition: right 0.3s;
  /* определяем цвет фона панели */
  background: #16a085;
  /* поверх других элементов */
  z-index: 2000;
}

.nav-toggle {
  /* абсолютно позиционируем */
  position: absolute;
  /* относительно правого края панели */
  right: 500px;
  /* отступ от верхнего края панели */
  top: 3em;
  /* внутренние отступы */
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: inherit;
  /* цвет текста */
  color: #dadada;
  /* вид курсора */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* размер шрифта */
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1;
  /* всегда поверх других элементов страницы */
  z-index: 2001;
  /* анимируем цвет текста при наведении */
  -webkit-transition: color .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: color .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: color .25s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 21px 5px black;
}

.nav-toggle:after {
  content: '\2630';
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* цвет текста при наведении */

.nav-toggle:hover {
  color: #f4f4f4;
}

[id='nav-toggle'] {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

[id='nav-toggle']:checked~.nav>.nav-toggle {
  left: auto;
  right: 2px;
  top: 1em;
}

[id='nav-toggle']:checked~.nav {
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: -4px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: -4px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow-y: auto;
}

[id='nav-toggle']:checked~main>article {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-500px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-500px);
  transform: translateX(-500px);
}

[id='nav-toggle']:checked~.nav>.nav-toggle:after {
  content: '\2715';
}

body {
  -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bugfix {
  to {
    padding: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  html,
  body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  html,
  body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .nav {
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none
  }
}


/**
 * Формируем стиль заголовка (логотип) панели 
*/

.nav h2 {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) -1px -1px 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 1px 1px 1px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transition: opacity 0.8s, transform 0.8s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.8s, -ms-transform 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.8s, -moz-transform 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.8s, -webkit-transform 0.8s;
}

.nav h2 a {
  color: #dadada;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/*плавное появление заголовка (логотипа) при раскрытии панели */

[id='nav-toggle']:checked~.nav h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
}

.nav>ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav>ul>li {
  line-height: 2.5;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
  transform: translateX(50%);
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s .1s, -webkit-transform .5s .1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s .1s, -moz-transform .5s .1s;
  -ms-transition: opacity .5s .1s, -ms-transform .5s .1s;
  transition: opacity .5s .1s, transform .5s .1s;
}

[id='nav-toggle']:checked~.nav>ul>li {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}


/* определяем интервалы появления пунктов меню */

.nav>ul>li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s .2s, -webkit-transform .5s .2s;
  transition: opacity .5s .2s, transform .5s .2s;
}

.nav>ul>li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s .3s, -webkit-transform .5s .3s;
  transition: opacity .5s .3s, transform .5s .3s;
}

.nav>ul>li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s .4s, -webkit-transform .5s .4s;
  transition: opacity .5s .4s, transform .5s .4s;
}

.nav>ul>li:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s .5s, -webkit-transform .5s .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s .5s, transform .5s .5s;
}

.nav>ul>li:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s .6s, -webkit-transform .5s .6s;
  transition: opacity .5s .6s, transform .5s .6s;
}

.nav>ul>li:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s .7s, -webkit-transform .5s .7s;
  transition: opacity .5s .7s, transform .5s .7s;
}


/**
 * оформление ссылок пунктов меню
 */

.nav>ul>li>a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #dadada;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* плавный переход */
  -webkit-transition: color .5s ease, padding .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .5s ease, padding .5s ease;
  transition: color .5s ease, padding .5s ease;
}


/**
 * состояние ссылок меню при наведении
 */

.nav>ul>li>a:hover,
.nav>ul>li>a:focus {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 15px;
}


/**
 * линия подчеркивания ссылок меню
 */

.nav>ul>li>a:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width 0s ease;
  transition: width 0s ease;
}

.nav>ul>li>a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #3bc1a0;
  -webkit-transition: width .5s ease;
  transition: width .5s ease;
}


/**
 * анимируем линию подчеркивания 
 * ссылок при наведении
 */

.nav>ul>li>b:hover:before {
  width: 0%;
  background: #3bc1a0;
  -webkit-transition: width .5s ease;
  transition: width .5s ease;
}

.nav>ul>li>a:hover:after {
  width: 0%;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: width 0s ease;
  transition: width 0s ease;
}

.mask-content {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

[id='nav-toggle']:checked~.mask-content {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, visibility .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s, visibility .5s;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" hidden>

<nav class="nav">

  <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle" onclick></label>

  <h2 class="logo"></h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>Новости</h3>
      <li><a href="https://habr.com/company/spbifmo/blog/426347">Уязвимость в PlayStation 4 — набор символов в сообщении для пользователя удаленно превращает приставку в почти «кирпич»</a>
        <li><a href="https://habr.com/post/426317">1155 vs 2011. В бой идут одни старики</a>
          <li><a href="https://habr.com/post/426333">Microsoft выпустил код MS-DOS 1.25 и 2.0 под лицензией MIT</a>
            <li><a href="https://habr.com/post/426303">Краткий экскурс по основным моментам Zend Framework</a>
              <li><a href="https://habr.com/company/1cloud/blog/426335/">«Марсианская технология»: почему дата-центры переходят на топливные ячейки</a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть простое решение: просто добавить атребут `checked` на инпут.

`<input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" hidden checked >`

Comment: Да спасибо вам добрый человек, 4 часа уже голову ломаю !!!!!

Comment: @Barbrust отметьте ответ как верный(галочка слева), если он Вам помог